# CodeIgniter counter using "global" variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie CodeIgniter developer and I must say my frustration rached to new heights when I realized I wasn't able to make work a very simple click counter.  The idea is you click on a button and get the number of clicks counted.
This is the view simplecounter_view:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<html>
    <body>  
     <?php
        echo '<form action="'. base_url().'index.php/simplecounter" method="POST">';        
        echo '<font color="blue">Click counter:' . $counter . '</font><br/><br/>';              
        echo '<input type="submit" name="myform" value="Count">';
        echo '</form>';
     ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you click the form button it will call the SimpleCounter Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class SimpleCounter extends CI_Controller { 
    public function __construct() {             
        parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function index() {
        $myform=$this->input->post('myform');
        if ($myform=='Count') {
            Globals::setCounter(Globals::getCounter()+1);
        }   
        $data['counter'] = Globals::getCounter();
        $this->load->view('simplecounter_view', $data);         
    }
}
```

Finally, I am using a Globals class with the property $counter in order to keep its value "global" and accessible from the Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Globals {
     private static $initialized=false;
     private static $counter;   

    private function __construct() {}
    private static function initialize() {
        if (self::$initialized)
            return;

        self::$counter = 0;
        self::$initialized = true;    
     }    
    public static function setCounter($n) {
        self::initialize();
        self::$counter = $n;
    }
    public static function getCounter() {
        self::initialize();
        return self::$counter;
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work as I expected. The click counter doesn't get updated on every user click. It seems to me the Globals class gets recreated every time one of its methods is called and so $counter is reset to zero and $initialized to false.

I understand there might be different approaches (like defining $counter in config.php) though I think using a separated class for keeping $counter is more elegant. What am I missing here? Where did I get it all wrong? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: PHP is stateless so it will be reset. If you want to persist the counter then you need some to store it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I totally missed that point. I understand then that I have to use some mechanism (session, database,...) to store the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTTP is stateless protocol, once the http response is sent to the requesting browser all your variables get lost.

> In computing, a stateless protocol is a communications protocol that
>   treats each request as an independent transaction that is unrelated to
>   any previous request so that the communication consists of independent
>   pairs of request and response.

You need to save the counter in a database.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am going to follow your suggestion.

Comment: @JaapVanDiermen Please feel free to select the answer to mark it as solved. :)